# What's the price of a Vietnamese tourist visa in Laos for an Australian national?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, price, vietnam, laos

I'm in Vientiane, Laos and contemplating returning to Vietnam where I was about five or six months ago.

That time I got my visa in Cambodia (Sihanoukville) where it cost $60 USD.

I intend to head to Savannakhet, where there's a Vietnamese consulate, apply for the visa there, then head east to Vietnam.

But the [Wikivoyage page on Savannakhet](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Savannakhet) says a Vietnam tourist visa there costs $75 USD. Could that be the price for Americans and the price for Australians is the same $60 I paid in Cambodia?

Neither the [Wikipedia page about Vietnamese visas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Vietnam) nor the [homepage of the consulate](http://www.vietnamconsulate-savanakhet.org/en) has further visa price details that I can find.

Comment: They do have a phone number listed on their page

Answer (score 4):

Today I went to the consular office of the Vietnamese Embassy here in **Vientiane** to ask them.

**Whether you want a one-month or three-month visa, the price is the same**:

- **$60 USD** to pick up your passport after three working days.
- **$70 USD** for express service - pick up your passport the following day.

I asked the staff there if the prices are the same at the **Savannakhet** consulate but they said they didn't know.

They did not ask my nationality and when I asked if that mattered and told them I'm Australian the price was the same. It made me think these prices cover all of the "typical tourist countries" but might be different if you're from a developing country I suppose. The staff were not very interested in my questions.

Answer (score 1):

Vietnam visa fee reduce from 23 Nov 2015 (according to Circular 157/2015/TT)
From 23 Nov 2015, Vietnam visa fee will be as below:
- 1 month validity single entry visa & less than 3 months validity visa: 25 USD (instead of 45 USD)
- 1 month validity multiple entries visa: 50 USD (instead of 95 USD)
- Other validities from 3 months validity to 1 year validity: as current (95 – 135 USD)

Comment: D'oh - three days after my flight home! Next trip ...